# Greasemonkey script to work on dynamically loaded posts on Facebook

Tags: javascript, facebook, greasemonkey

I wrote a Greasemonkey script and it affect the firstly loaded posts on Facebook. 
but after you scroll down on the feed, the script doesn't work on the newly loaded posts.

Is there a way to re-run the script for those posts, or something like that? can anyone help me?

Comment: Post your greasemonkey script and maybe I could help you out.  It really depends on how you are 'affecting' the posts.

Answer (score 9):

**Update:**
This question and answer are very old and [`DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3).
I no longer recommend this approach. Instead see:

- [Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281441/fire-greasemonkey-script-on-ajax-request)
- [Run Greasemonkey script on the same page, multiple times?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11195658/run-greasemonkey-script-on-the-same-page-multiple-times)
- [Choosing and activating the right controls on an AJAX-driven site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15048223/choosing-and-activating-the-right-controls-on-an-ajax-driven-site)
- Or use `MutationObserver` via a library like [Mutation Summary](https://github.com/rafaelw/mutation-summary), or similar.

---

---

**Old answer:**

Yes, since you are using Firefox, you can trigger off the `DOMSubtreeModified` event.

To do this, first wrap the code part of your current script in a function; for example:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name            Facebook Fixer
// ==/UserScript==

function LocalMain ()
{
    //--- Do all of your actions here.
}

LocalMain (); //-- Fire GM script once, normally.
```

---

Next, find the node that contains the newly loaded posts.   Say that you find that it is a `div` with the id *"All_posts_go_here"* (I don't use Facebook, be sure to find the correct node, and do not use `body`, the browser will slow to a crawl).

Once you've identified the correct node, you can set the event listener.  But, you also need a short time delay because the node changes come hundreds at a time and you need to wait until the current batch is done.

So, putting it all together, the code looks like this:

```
if (window.top != window.self)  //don't run on frames or iframes
    return;

function LocalMain ()
{
    //--- Do all of your actions here.
}

LocalMain (); //-- Fire GM script once, normally.


var PostsChangedByAJAX_Timer    = '';
//--- Change this next line to find the correct element; sample shown.
var PostContainerNode           = document.getElementById ('All_posts_go_here');

PostContainerNode.addEventListener ("DOMSubtreeModified", PageBitHasLoaded, false);


function PageBitHasLoaded (zEvent)
{
    /*--- Set and reset a timer so that we run our code (LocalMain() ) only
        AFTER the last post -- in a batch -- is added.  Adjust the time if needed, but
        half a second is a good all-round value.
    */
    if (typeof PostsChangedByAJAX_Timer == "number")
    {
        clearTimeout (PostsChangedByAJAX_Timer);
        PostsChangedByAJAX_Timer  = '';
    }
    PostsChangedByAJAX_Timer      = setTimeout (function() {LocalMain (); }, 555);
}
```

---

Beware that I'm assuming the node is not an iframe.  If it is, then a different approach may be required.

Comment: The posts aren't in an IFRAME, fortunately. They are LI elements with ids like "stream_story_xxxxxx" where xxxxxx is a 23 character unique code, in a UL element with id="home_stream".