# Why is the DOMSubtreeModified event deprecated in DOM level 3?

Tags: javascript, dom, dom-events, deprecated, dom3

Why is the DOMSubtreeModified event [deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) and what are we supposed to use instead?

Answer (score 53, accepted):

If you [scroll down a bit](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#events-mutationevents), you see:

> Warning! The `MutationEvent` interface was introduced in DOM Level 2
>   Events, but has not yet been completely and interoperably implemented
>   across user agents. In addition, there have been critiques that the
>   interface, as designed, introduces a performance and implementation
>   challenge. A new specification is under development with the aim of
>   addressing the use cases that mutation events solves, but in more
>   performant manner. Thus, this specification describes mutation events
>   for reference and completeness of legacy behavior, but deprecates the
>   use of both the `MutationEvent` interface and the `MutationNameEvent`
>   interface.

The replacement API is [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver), which are fully specified [in the DOM Living Standard](https://dom.spec.whatwg.org/#mutation-observers) that supercedes all of the DOM level X silliness.

Comment: @ TJ - no down. The one above is *DOMNodeRemovedFromDocument*. :-)

Comment: Replacement will come in DOM Level 4 http://dvcs.w3.org/hg/domcore/raw-file/tip/Overview.html#mutation-observers and it seems there is some progress in Chromium https://bugs.webkit.org/show_bug.cgi?id=73851

Comment: A great hack to replace the `MutationEvent` interface is [`animationStart` and some CSS](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13835369/237285).

Comment: The problem of the animationStart being, it only works for insertion of nodes. Not for node removal, attribute edition or text changes. It's also single-node, where `DOMSubtreeModified` allows watching a whole tree from a root node.

Answer (score 28):

I think the replacement will be mutation observers: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

```
var whatToObserve = {childList: true, attributes: true, subtree: true, attributeOldValue: true, attributeFilter: ['class', 'style']};
var mutationObserver = new MutationObserver(function(mutationRecords) {
  $.each(mutationRecords, function(index, mutationRecord) {
    if (mutationRecord.type === 'childList') {
      if (mutationRecord.addedNodes.length > 0) {
        //DOM node added, do something
      }
      else if (mutationRecord.removedNodes.length > 0) {
        //DOM node removed, do something
      }
    }
    else if (mutationRecord.type === 'attributes') {
      if (mutationRecord.attributeName === 'class') {
        //class changed, do something
      }
    }
  });
});
mutationObserver.observe(document.body, whatToObserve);
```

Comment: I fail to understand the improvement that this makes. The code needed for achieving the same result seems to be bigger and less intuitive, and I don't get the internal benefits of how it works.