# In JavaScript or with jQuery is there an event that will be triggered when the contents of a div change?

Tags: javascript, jquery, drupal, jquery-events

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Detect element content changes with jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery)

I am trying to modify the selected option in a select that appears in a module window after a file is uploaded. I have yet to find a way to hook into the end of this ajax callback. So I am wondering if there is a way to monitor the parent div for content changes and then activate it on that.

I don't think this is possible, but I wanted to see if anyone else knew better than me.

I am using Drupal 6 and jQuery 1.3 on this site with a lot of modules.

Comment: There are no generic events for div contents changing that are widely supported that I'm aware of.  If you post the ajax code, there should be a way to know when that event has completed.

Comment: Try having a look at this, seems to be what you are after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1091661/detect-element-content-changes-with-jquery

Comment: I figured as much. I have never heard of such a thing, but I had to ask.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`DOMSubtreeModified`. But they are [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3).

For your case, it's better to intercept the AJAX request. This can be done in this way, without side effects:

```
(function($) {
    var $ajax = $.ajax;
    $.ajax = function(url, settings) {
        // Detect something, See http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/
        // If settings does not exist, then settings = url

        $ajax.call(this, url, settings); // Call normal AJAX thing
    };
})(jQuery);
```

Instead of intercepting all AJAX requests, you can also add an [`ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxComplete/) event.

Comment: Thanks, this did it. I actually used your ajaxComplete suggestion. Perfect. Thanks again!

Comment: I apologize. I put in the fix a few days ago and I confused this with another. I have adjusted my comment and given you credit for the fix.