# How to execute jQuery code if a div display style changes from none to block?

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm trying to execute jQuery code when a div's style changes from `display: none;` to `display: block;`

I'm using tabs that's why this div's style changes like this, and this jQuery code should only be running when viewing this tab only.

so how can I achieve this ?

and thanks.

EDIT: I tried `.is(':visible');` and it only works if we load the page and this div is visible, not if this div will be visible later.

Comment: Why not execute the code when a user clicks on the other tab?

Comment: yes maybe this will work, but I want to know if it's possible to do this using jQuery, listening when something happened ?

Comment: @Alnitak ok so I guess I have to do it the way Celos suggested above.

Comment: @Peter yeah, it's normally quite easy to trap any event which changes the displayed tab.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're looking for are [DOM Mutation Events](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-2-Events/events.html#Events-eventgroupings-mutationevents), which can raise an event when a DOM element is inserted, deleted or modified.

Unfortunately they were never well supported, and [were deprecated in DOM3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3).

In any event (no pun intended), in your case it would be simpler just to catch whatever UI event it is that causes the tab to be displayed.

Answer (score 2):

```
if($("#myTab").is(':visible')){
    here is your code ...
}
```

Comment: missing colon from your `visible` psuedo selector

Comment: No worries, thought it was just a typo. :)

Comment: OP appears to want an event raised, not to test the visibility

Answer (score 2):

try something like this:

```
if($(DIV).is(':visible')) {   // DIV => valid selector of your target
   // execute your code
}
```

**OR:**

```
if($('body').on('EVENTNAME', 'DIV:visible')) {   // DIV => valid selector of your target
   // execute your code
}
```

Comment: OP appears to want an event raised, not to test the visibility

Answer (score -1):

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $(your tab container).click(function(){
        //set none property to all of your id's
        var obj=$this;
        if(obj){
            $("your id").style.display="block"; // set block to your current item
        }
    });
});
```

or

```
if($("you id").is('visible')){
    //do it
}
```

Comment: Does a jQuery object even have access to the `style` property? I thought it din't. So `$("your id").style.display="block";` won't work. you either have to change it to `$("your id")[0].style.display="block";` or `$("your id").get(0).style.display="block";` or use the jQuery object itself: `$("your id").attr('style','display:block');` or something similar

Comment: the comment above mine is correct. the code you provided throws a syntax error.