# JQuery does not execute on $(document).change()

Tags: jquery, css, asp.net-mvc

I need to make some JQuery execute when the page/document has changed - in this case, when a div with a specific CSS class is displayed.

I have the following JQuery code:

```
   <script>
           $(document).change(function () {
               if ($('.validation_errors').length) {
                   alert("test");
               }
           }
    </script>
```

However, it does not execute and display the alert. Am I missing something here?

Comment: `change` event is never fired on `document`. It is restricted only to inputs, textareas and selects. What exactly do you want to achieve? What do you mean by "page/document change"?

Comment: More to the point, the `change` event isn't fired in response to DOM changes. A handler on document *will* catch `change` events fired on inputs inside the document, but this question is nothing to do with `change` events

Answer (score 25, accepted):

Change is only for input, textarea or select elements. Instead you need to bind a function to the `DOMSubtreeModified` mutation event:

```
$(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
   if ($('.validation_errors').length) {
       alert("test");
   }
});
```

EDIT: If your target browsers support it, you should use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead.

Comment: Probably a bad idea to use `DOMSubtreeModified`, please see http://stackoverflow.com/a/6659678/733347. Unfortunately it isn't implemented cross-browser

Comment: I waiting till someone posted that :p The truth is that although deprecated there's little alternatives out there to something that works in _most_ browsers (although that link you posted from the jQuery forums is interesting and something I'll give a go, thanks for that).

Comment: @Aravin You should use [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) instead

Answer (score 2):

You can't monitor changes in the DOM is this manner. Quote from the jQuery docs:

> The change event is sent to an element when its value changes. This
>   event is limited to  elements,  boxes and 
>   elements. - http://api.jquery.com/change/

If you're looking to execute code when there is a DOM change, you may need to either set up and interval which checks the DOM or use [this technique](http://forum.jquery.com/topic/bind-dom-change#14737000000039031) provided by a poster on the jQuery forums.

There is the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, but it is scarcely available in current browsers, so I personally wouldn't recommend its use. See [this stackoverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6659678/733347) for further details on that

Answer (score 0):

Your syntax is wrong too buddy! If you're going to do it, do it within document ready, .change is very limited and wont fire on a new page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    if($('.classOrId').length){
        //do something if it exists
    };
});
```