# call many functions on document change

Tags: javascript, jquery, function, namespaces

I have few namespaces and I want to reinitialize function inside namespaces on document change in order to be reinitialized every time when the document is modified (*modified = adding/removing new sections on existing dom ).
I have tried this but not working so far:

```
 ;namespaceName= {
        namespaceFunction1: function() {
            $( selector ).on('click', function() {
                //my first function run here
            })
        },
        // ************second function in namespace***************/

        namespaceFunction2: function() {
            $(secondSelector).on('click', function() {
            //my second function run here
            })
        }
    }

    $(document).on('change', namespaceName.namespaceFunction1() );
    $(document).on('change', namespaceName.namespaceFunction2() );
```

Pls help, ty.

Comment: There is no document change event (and you would need to remove the empty parenthesis from the functions anyway)... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495128/jquery-does-not-execute-on-document-change

Comment: `document` does not have a `change` event.

Comment: @Archer,@kei so according t your knowledge this function will never work, right?                                  $(document).on('change', 'input:radio', function(){
    var el = $(this).closest('.input-group').find('input:text');
    $('input:text').prop('disabled', function(){
        return !el.is(this);
    })
})

Comment: That's entirely different.  That's looking for a change event on all radios *within* the document.  That's not what your code above is doing.  It's trying to capture a change event on the document object itself, which does not exist.

Comment: If you explain what it is you're trying to achieve then maybe we can help.  What do you mean by "document change"?

Comment: @archer yes but that function if running up no matter if the dom was modified, maybe I have not explained very well my question but I need something that reinitialize methods from namespace when dom is modified. document change = dom modified in my opinion.

Comment: I'll post an answer for you then.

Comment: @Archer yes something like that ty   :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this...

```
$(document).on("DOMSubtreeModified", function () {
    namespaceName.namespaceFunction1();
    namespaceName.namespaceFunction2();
});
```

It fires your 2 functions on the `DOMSubtreeModified` event, which is basically what you were looking for - when the DOM changes.

Answer (score 1):

sounds like you need to listen for the DOMSubtreeModified event like this:

```
$('body').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
      //your code here
});
```