# jQuery changing text of an element if another element has a certain class

Tags: jquery

I am trying to change the text value of an element if another element has a class but what I am currently doing is showing no results.

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#number').text('00');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#test').removeClass('initial-number').addClass('change-number');
    }, 500);
});

$(document).change(function () {
    if ($('#test').hasClass('change-number') === true) {
        $('#number').text('10');
    };
});
```

```css
#test {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}

.initial-number {
  background: blue;
}

.change-number {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="number"></span>
<div class="initial-number" id="test"></div>
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [JQuery does not execute on $(document).change()](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12495128/jquery-does-not-execute-on-document-change)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this

```js
   $(document).ready(function () {
$('#number').text('00');

setTimeout(function(){
  $('#test').removeClass('initial-number').addClass('change-number');
   $('#number').text('10');
  }, 500);
});
```

```css
#test {
  height: 2em;
  width: 2em;
}

.initial-number {
  background: blue;
}

.change-number {
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<span id="number"></span>
<div class="initial-number" id="test"></div>
```

Comment: "Try this" answers are **not useful**. Say **what** you did, and **why**.

Answer (score 4):

`document` has no `change` event; that's only for form field elements.

You can use [mutation observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) for this, watching for changes to the attributes of the element in question. They're well-supported on modern browsers; on slightly less-modern browsers, you can find a polyfill using the old mutation events. On really older browsers, you'll have to poll.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply include it in the setTimeout function:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#number').text('00');

    setTimeout(function () {
        $('#test').removeClass('initial-number').addClass('change-number');
        if ($('#test').hasClass('change-number')) {
            $('#number').text('10');
        };
    }, 500);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
 $(document).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function () {
       if ($('#test').hasClass('change-number') === true) {
        $('#number').text('10');
      };
    });
```

Change is only for input, textarea or select elements.

Comment: Mutation events were deprecated years ago, and are actively being removed from modern browsers.