# Javascript 'div empty' event listener

Tags: javascript, events, listener

Is there a way to have a listener for when a div element is empty?

```
 $('#myDiv').emptyEvent(function(){

)};
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Is there a jQuery DOM change listener?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-jquery-dom-change-listener)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should run David's code inside an event handler, such as `DOMNodeInserted`, `DOMCharacterDataModified`, or `DOMSubtreeModified`. The latter being the most recommended. For example:

```
$('#myDiv').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function(){
   if ( $('#myDiv').html() == "" ) {

   }
)};
```

**Edit:** Such implementation is however *deprecated*, as stated in the comments. An alternative implementation, as suggested by david, is the following:

```
// select the target node
var target = $("#myDiv")[0];

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
   mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
      if($("#myDiv").html() == ""){
         // Do something.
      }
   });    
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = { attributes: true, childList: true, characterData: true };

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
```

Comment: Just be aware that those mutation events are deprecated and have been replaced by the mutation observer: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/MutationObserver

Comment: And sad thing is it is [deprecated](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3)

Comment: indeed they are I was just about to comment that

Comment: @david: I edited the answer. That might work, although I'm not sure if the mutation observer is supported among other browsers...

Comment: The number of davids on this site is too damn high.

Comment: ...so it works only in firefox :( I'm disappointed that such useful event isn't crossbrowser implemented yet