# why jquery .bind() is not working in this case?

Tags: jquery, bind

What is the problem in my bind method using jquery?

**Working**

```
var Element = htmlBody.find('tag');
$(Element ).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
    console.log(Element[0]);
    //code come here
});
```

**Not Working**

```
var obj = {};
var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2'];
for (index in tags) {
    obj[index] = htmlBody.find(tags[index]);
    $(obj[index]).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
        console.log(obj[index][0]);
        //  code doe not come here
    });  
}
```

Comment: You should not use `for... in` to iterate over arrays. In your case, you're probably hitting its `length` property. Use a counter variable instead.

Comment: try to use the $.each() / iterate using a temp variable

Comment: `DOMSubtreeModified` event is deprecated.. click here for more info: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3

Comment: Aside from some peculiarities in your code, which I assume is a truncated version for demo purposes, it works in a fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/HEYXm/

Comment: also another problem is the buggy use of closure variable `index` in the callback

Comment: I think a better approach will be http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/ZyJwH/2/

Comment: which version of jquery your using ? because As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.

Answer (score 1):

Try the following:

```
var obj = {};
var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2'];
$.each(tags, function(idx, item) {
    obj[idx] = htmlBody.find(tags[idx]);
    $(obj[index]).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
        console.log(item);
    });  
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It is recommended to use the `on` function instead of `bind()`.  Also you need to iterate through the elements with a `for` loop.

```
var obj = {};
var tags = ['tag1', 'tag2'];
for (var i = 0; i < tags.length;i++) {
    obj[i] = htmlBody.find(tags[i]); //not exactly sure what htmlBody.find does
    var item = obj[i][0];
    $(obj[i]).('DOMSubtreeModified', function(event) {
        console.log(item);
    });  
}
```

Comment: beware of the closure variable `i` in the callback

Comment: @ArunPJohny Thanks, I missed that.

Comment: As of jQuery 1.7, the .on() method is the preferred method for attaching event handlers to a document. For earlier versions, the .bind() method is used for attaching an event handler directly to elements.