# Detecting new tr or content change

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a bunch of tr, that represent a cart

```
<tr class="cart_row">
  <td>Product</td>
  <td>£20</td>
  <td>2</td>
</tr>
<tr class="cart_row">
  <td>Product 2</td>
  <td>£50</td> 
  <td>1</td>
</tr>
```

This gets updated via ajax when an item has been added.

What I'm looking to do, is to detect when the cart has been updated, i.e a new `<tr>` with a class of `cart_row`or if the contents of an existing `<tr>` has been updated

Can I do this with jQuery?

Thanks

Comment: It would be easier to just hook into the success callback of the ajax function that does the updating, as there is no reliable event to use for this (you could use mutation events / observers, but why ?)

Comment: How does the cart get updated? can you post that code?

Comment: I have a success in the ajax callback, I just need an esy way to detect whether or not these `<tr>`s have changed or if a new one has been added to the dom

Comment: Have you checked my answer? if you post your ajax code I can adapt it better.

Comment: @Sergio it is just a simple on click of a button. It passes in a 'item_id' if there is a number in the quantity, it adds a row or updates the item in a cart sidebar

Comment: Well, then you have a function with a condition already, and you know wether or not any elements where inserted, why do you need another function to check if the elements are really there, when you're the one inserting them.

Comment: Updated my example with a Ajax example, please check (click twice)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would suggest this:

```
// a function to make a string out of thew data
function getData() {
    var data = $('tr.cart_row td').map(function (el) {
        return this.innerHTML;
    }).get().toString();
    return data;
}

//before the Ajax:
var valuesBefore = getData();

// do Ajax

//after the Ajax, ideally inside the callback (remeber ajax is async)
if (valuesBefore != getData()){ //do something };
```

### [Example](http://jsfiddle.net/mLfQ3/)

Comment: but this will always compare html before any ajax call, and html after each ajax call. If you can do more than one ajax call, you would like to compare between ajax call and ajax call-1, no (if that's understandable) ? So doing this in success callback before updating dom would be better, I think.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, sure. Difficould to know when OP didn't post any code for ajax.

Comment: @RaphaëlAlthaus, added a example with ajax echo.

Answer (score 0):

You can, with this:

```
$("#yourTable").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("table changed! row added");
});
```

See the browser support here: http://www.quirksmode.org/dom/events/#t18

*EDIT* However, it's getting deprecated

Hope this helps. Cheers

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3

Comment: I had a feeling, wasn't sure either but went to look now and found it. Also learned.

Answer (score -1):

As far as I know, there is no event for this action. You should implement this with the help of `setTimeout` function. Set a function which checks if the `count` of needed elements changes.

Comment: You case will not work, if item was added then other removed, + there is events which you can catch on item added, deleted etc.