# DOMSubtreeModified - check if only first item in container has changed

Tags: javascript, jquery, dom

I am trying to listen for changes inside container, lets assume `.container`

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
  <div class="item"></div>
</div>
```

each item has various angular js attributes, data attributes etc that change  quiet a lot, as well as text in them so:

```
$('.container').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    console.log("change");
});
```

prints out a lot of "change" text. I want to decrease this and at the same time I only need to check if first item inside container changed, therefore how can I only check this?

Comment: Unrelated, but, useful => [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3)

Comment: Do you mean first item content changed or the whole first item element? Anyway, using angularjs (or even just in js), that's surely not the way to check it, using `DOMSubtreeModified` event

Comment: @A.Wolff first item in general, can be content or element as a whole. I am personally not using angular, this is for chrome extension, I only mentioned it, as product that has items I listen to, uses angular, thus its attributes.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should filter out event target, using e.g:

```
$('.container').on("DOMSubtreeModified", function (e) {
    if($(e.target).is('.item:first-child')) { 
        console.log(e.target);
    }
});
```

Comment: e.target seems to be conatiner all the time

Comment: Not on chrome as i tested it