# simple jQuery variable event

Tags: jquery

I know this is a basic question, but these are the ones that get me.

I define a variable:

```
var img_w = $('#image').width();
```

Then I do this:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    if (img_w > 100) {
        //do stuff
    }
});
```

My image is loaded from a separate html, styled with jQuery, and then fits the >100 criteria, but it's too late. So I try:

```
$(window).load(function()
$(window).on('load' function()
$(window).onload(function()
$(window).ready(function()
```

And so on an so forth... But to no avail, because of the order of events.

So the simple solution is to make an event for when img_w is greater than 100. But for some reason I can't figure out the best way to do this. I'm sure there's a simple solution I'm missing. Any help will be much appreciated. :)

edit: To expand on you questions about what's going on; A div is to have it's width set to img_w. The image that img_w get's it's value from is loaded from an external html file. The jQuery to set the div width, and where the variable is made, is in the external html file.

Comment: Sounds like what you are looking for is a mutation event, but mutation events are kind of shady and not well supported. You said you use jQuery to style it.. so add a call to `someCallbackFunction()` to pop whatever you want at the same place where you change the width. If this is not possible for you, then alt would be to wrap your logic in a `setTimeout` to keep looking for a change every n milliseconds.

Comment: It helps if you first explain the problem, what are you trying to do?

Comment: I just want to make something that fires after all the stuff I had going.

Comment: @Brad put width() code inside doc ready block. If it is outside it will get executed when `#image` element is not even initialized.

Comment: How are you loading your external image? The clue is in there. I assume you are using ajax? In that case you should add the `//do stuff` part to the success callback of that.

Comment: What does that mean?  The ready event fires once (unless you have some async postback / update panel scenerio).  What triggers the chagning of the width?  Wherever it changes is your callback function where you //do stuff.

Comment: @pratikwebdev Sorry for that being unclear, the bit where I define the variable is in doc ready.

Comment: @CrayonViolent What would the setTimeout solution look like?

Comment: try to put the variable value setting part inside the ready function above the if sentence.

Comment: @Brad `#image` element will get loaded first which will have some width based on structure of page. Second once you load an image in it it may change width of an element. All this happens on page load. Once it is done `document.ready()` gets called. If you are initializing `img_w` outside of doc ready as part of JS and if it is being loaded before HTML / body it wont hold a value since `#image` element is not yet loaded. I hope it helps. Try putting it inside doc ready. Check the value before and after.

Comment: @Brad `siteTimeout` solution would [look like this](https://jsfiddle.net/9vnftcnh/), but the accepted answer is the custom event binder/trigger is the `someCallbackFunction()` method I mentioned as the preferred solution, so go with that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can make use of `DOMSubtreeModified` event which gets executed anytime there is a change in the property of the element.

```
$('#image').bind("DOMSubtreeModified", CheckHeight);
```

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/

**UPDATE** : Since DOMSubtreeModified is depreciated and may no longer be compatible with all browsers, the other possible option is to delegate an event handler to the element and manually invoke the change event during an external event invokation:

```
$('#image').bind("DOMModified", CheckHeight);
$("#image").triggerHandler('DOMModified');
```

Here's an example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/6d5ry9br/1/

Comment: I think this might work for my application, but is there a reason the fiddle works in firefox but not chrome?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3

Comment: Thanks for the link. I guess I need another solution?

Comment: @Brad: The other possible option that i can think of is to create an eventHandler and invoke it manually. Added it in the UPDATE section.

Comment: This updated solution works great for my application. Thanks. :)

Comment: Sure. Glad i could help :)