# dynamically appending elements on dynamically created elements

Tags: jquery, ruby-on-rails

I have a modal with dynamic content. 
e.g. 
I can create an item by typing someting in a textbox and hit enter. 
After I hit enter I want a notification below the textbox, which itself was dynamically created.

normally I'd just put this in my .js.erb

```
$("#idOfTextbox").append("some waring")
```

but as I mentioned the textbox with id: idOfTextbox was created dynamically and because of that this approach doesnt work.

I read plenty about this and I think I roughly understand the problem, normaly you'd do something like this

```
$(document).on("click", "#idOfTextbox", function(){
  $(this).append("some warning");
};
```

but I don't really want to bind it to a specific event, I just want to append the message when the controller renders the .js.erb file

I thought mb something like .on("load", might work, but I had no success so far.

I'd really appreciate any help.

Comment: check this : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34518236/simple-jquery-variable-event/34518314#34518314. Your best option is to append the text when idOfTextbox is created dynamically

Comment: well I could has write the messages before and only show/ hide them :D or I try to render append the message on success of the ajax call itself, instead of doing it inside the .js.erb.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

alright the answer was easier than expected.

I just replaced the item inside the success part of the ajax request itself:

**this sends the content of #role_name textfeld to the controller and renders replaces the exsisting div with #newrole id with my text**

```
$(function(){
  $("body").on("keyup", function(e){
    if ( e.which == 13 ) {
      role_name = $("#role_name").val();

      $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      dataType: "script",
      url: '/roles',
      data: {role: {name: role_name} },
      success: function(){
        $("#newrole").replaceWith("creation succesful bitches");
        }
      });
    }
  });
})
```

if you want to access the response of the controller just call the function like this

```
success: function(html){
```

and inside html variable schould be the content of your controller response.

note: I could replaceWith but not append, dunno why...

Answer (score 3):

Try this :

```
$('body').append("<div id='idOfTextbox'></div>");
$(document).find('#idOfTextbox').append("some value");
```

Example : https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2rhasve1/2/

Comment: I think this only works because the div is gets appended, but when I render a partial I actually replace it. and in this case it doesn't work. https://jsfiddle.net/2rhasve1/6/

Comment: You need to use replaceWith instead of replace. https://jsfiddle.net/DinoMyte/2rhasve1/7/

Comment: yea I just noticed I am already using replaceWith, but I still doesn't work. And pretty sure it only works because it is inside fiddle. I'll go with this solution: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33059192/jquery-find-dynamically-created-element-without-events. doing it inside the call back seems the best solution. I have always used the .js.erb solution before, but hopefully I'll get it to work. I'm not even rendering a partial in this case, so there schould be no problem.