# How to detect option content change in dropdown using jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, events

I have a dropdown field, options of which will be changed dynamically.
Is there a way to capture the event, whenever the set of options inside the dropdown is changed?

I do not want to capture the option change i.e

```
$(".dropdown").on("contentChange", function(){
    //do something
})
```

Rather, I want to capture the event, when the set of options inside the dropdown gets modified. 
How can i attach a handler, which will get trigger functions when option set changes.

Comment: You could use a Mutation Obeserver to check when the DOM within the `select` changes but that's not well supported in older browsers. Alternatively you could just `trigger()` your own event when you change the options yourself.

Comment: try with $(document).on("change", ".dropdown", function(){}); which will trigger for dynamically changing values

Comment: @ABUdhay that's for changing the selected value, not for changing the content of the select element itself - as the OP even states himself.

Comment: How are the options changing dynamically ? Probably you could do something in that code

Comment: I can add it in code that changes the option, but I wanted to explore if there are any options available for this

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is possible to watch DOM changes, in newset DOM specification we have **MutationObserver** to observe DOM. Working exampe

```js
MutationObserver = window.MutationObserver || window.WebKitMutationObserver;

//create observer
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations, observer) {
    
     console.log("Options have been changed");

});

//set to observe childs ( options )
observer.observe(document.querySelector(".dropdown"), {
  subtree: true,
  childList:true,
  attributes:true
});

//test change
$('button').on("click",function(){

  $(".dropdown").prepend("<option>New added option</option>");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option>Third</option>
  <option>Fourth</option>
</select>  
<button>Test button options change</button>
```

You can use also event **DOMSubtreeModified**. Event work on major browsers but is **DEPRECATED** . Working example:

```js
//add event    
$(".dropdown").on("DOMSubtreeModified", function(e){

  console.log('Options have been changed');

});

//change option example after button click
$('button').on("click",function(){

  $(".dropdown").prepend("<option>New added option</option>");
  
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select class="dropdown">
  <option>First</option>
  <option>Second</option>
  <option>Third</option>
  <option>Fourth</option>
</select>  
<button>Test button options change</button>
```

I added some example options modification after button click. Event will be called on any DOM change inside `select`.

Comment: [Why is the DOMSubtreeModified event deprecated in DOM level 3?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3)

Comment: @Mohammad article has 5 years and event is currently working with all major browsers. I think for his question it is good answer.

Comment: @MaciejSikora the SO answer might be 5 years old but you should look at the specs (https://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified) where it is officially stated that it is deprecated.

Comment: @Mohammad thanks. I added example with MutationObserver

Answer (score 2):

You can add your [custom event](https://learn.jquery.com/events/introduction-to-custom-events/) to DOM document and simulte it when content change using jquery [`.trigger()`](http://api.jquery.com/trigger/).

```js
$("button").click(function(){
    $("select > option:first").text("A1").trigger("contentChange");
});

$("select > option").on("contentChange", function(){
    console.log("Content changed");
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>Change content</button>
<select>
    <option>A</option>
    <option>B</option>
    <option>C</option>
</select>
```