# event, when div is changed

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have some DOM elements, like this

```
<div class='parent'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
</div>
```

How I can track event, when 'parent' div has changed? As example I'm add `<div>3</div>` programmatically, with `append()`, or i'm drag div3 to 'parent' div.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Detect changes in the DOM](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3219758/detect-changes-in-the-dom)

Comment: try this one - $('.myClass').on('DOMNodeInsertedIntoDocument', function() {
  alert('myClass was inserted into the DOM');
}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
$('.parent').on("DOMNodeInserted", function(){
  //your code
});
```

Comment: According to this [question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3), `DOMSubtreeModified` is deprecated.

Answer (score 1):

```
<div class='parent'>
    <div>1</div>
    <div>2</div>
</div>
<button id="add">Add to Div</button>
$(".parent").bind("DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
    alert("div added");
});
$("#add").click(function() {
    $(".parent").append("<div>3</div>");
});
```