# jQuery .bind on change some object with .class

Tags: javascript, jquery

i interested in learn how to correctly add .bind code to object, then he changed. This object is not unic and have class selector insted of id, but it have a `<div>` wrapper:

```
<div id="GDI">
  <table class = "Tiberium">
  ...
    <tbody>
     <tr>...</tr>
     ...
     <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>

<div id="NOD">
  <table class = "Tiberium">
  ...
    <tbody>
     <tr>...</tr>
     ...
     <tr>...</tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

The data changed in table with class "Tiberium" in `<tbody>` space (e.g. was added new row), i need simple alert then data changed in GDI table, but dont know how to do it.

Code that i tried:

```
$('.Tiberium').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', Alert);
```

Where Alert is function.
This code capture changes in both tables, and i got alerts then one of them changed. So how i can track changes only in "Tiberium" table in GDI space?

p.s. i'v tried `$('#NOD').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', Alert);`
but this code alert me 3 times in row, and it possible run every code in function 3 times. (i think it happend in case of this hierarchy).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The DOMSubTreeModified event is [deprecated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3). A better alternative to this solution is to use the MutationObserver.

```
var toBeObserved = document.getElementsByClassName('Tiberium');

if('MutationObserver' in window) { // ensure browser support
    var observer = new MutationObserver(myEventHandler); // instantiate
    observer.observe(toBeObserved, { // start observing
        childList : true,
        subtree   : true
    });
}
```

Everytime the `toBeObserved` element is mutated, the `myEventHandler` function will be called. You can add your custom code within this function.

Comment: i got many alerts in console after i assign observer, this script stop other scripts, idk why...

Comment: Removed `this` since you're probably not writing this within a function context, try now. Also, please elaborate which errors you get.

Comment: okay this method is answer for me, last question: how to correctly use `mutations` in callbacks?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please try following code:

```
$('.Tiberium').bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
    //check the parent div's id
    if($(this).parent().attr("id") == "GDI")
        Alert //your alert function call
});
```

Comment: tested in chrome console, have same problems if both tables get changes at the same time it count them all, so i recieve 2 alerts instead of 1.
`$('.Tiberium')` gives me link on 2 tables: `[table.Tiberium, table.Tiberium]`
`$('.Tiberium').parent().attr("id")` gives id of first space: `GDI`

Comment: yes...you will get count 2 for  `[table.Tiberium, table.Tiberium]` but my point is that the `if` condition we have added will get matched only for single `div` and `Alert` will have to come only once in that case.

Comment: strange, if i make this:
`$($($('.Tiberium')[1]).children()[1]).bind('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){
        alert('NOTICE');
});`
script alert 3 times in row, but this is bind to `<tbody>` ! Why it fires 3 times?