# jQuery function unwanted first call when page loads

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have a very straight forward jQuery ajax function in my 'funcs.js' file:

```
$('#selecDate').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){

  $.ajax({
               type: 'POST',
               url: '/revenue',
               data: {'name' : 'John Doe'},
               success: function(response){
                console.log(response);
                   $('th').text(response);
               },
               error: function(response){
                   console.log(response);
               },
             });
});
```

This is my 'funcs.js' file entire content. Why does this function being called automatically when page loads and how can i avoid it? thx

Comment: 1. Wrap it in `DOMContentLoaded` handler
2. `DOMSubtreeModified` has been deprecated for several years now

Comment: but the goal its to call ajax only when innerHTML of #selecDate changes...tried your solution and nothing happens...

Answer (score 1):

You're making the request when the DOM is modified. So on page load your DOM is modified and the event triggers.

Comment: i see..any idea how can i avoid the call for the first load? and why isn't it being called only when #selecDate called? thx

Comment: It's odd though. If the script is loaded before `#selectDate` exists, no handler should be attached. However, if the script is loaded after the element, the SubTree of that element doesn't change anymore, right?

Comment: $('#selecDate').on('DOMSubtreeModified', function(){}) - this function will hook up an event that, by definition, is called whenever the subtree is changed. If that event triggers, your function will run, so you have to make sure that you only hook up the event when you're ready to start watching for that event to occur.

Answer (score 0):

That handler should probably be inside of a $(document).ready(function(){}) since it's firing from the actual DOM being loaded. If you wait until the document is ready, then it'll only fire on DOM changes as I believe you're intending it to.

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#selecDate').on('DOMSubtreeModified',function(){
        $.ajax({
            type: 'POST',
            url: '/revenue',
            data: {'name' : 'John Doe'},
            success: function(response){
                         console.log(response);
                         $('th').text(response);
                     },
                     error: function(response){
                         console.log(response);
                     }
        });
    });
});
```

Comment: that's what i thought at the beginning but it didn't work.

Comment: Are you initializing that element using a framework? For example, is it a JQuery UI Date Selector? If so you need to make sure that this is being added after that initialization is made. If the initialization is being made in another file, then you'll need to make sure that you're importing this JS script after the one with the initialization.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Mutation Observers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) as [DOMSubtreeModified is deprecated](http://www.w3.org/TR/DOM-Level-3-Events/#event-type-DOMSubtreeModified).

[Why is the DOMSubtreeModified event deprecated in DOM level 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3)