# How to detect, when content of an element changes

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I am looking for a way to watch for dynamically populated (no page reload) content inside an element so that I can add a class to another element.

I have this so far:

HTML

```
<div class="message-container">
  <div class="messages error"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages success"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span></div>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">...</div>
```

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  if($.trim($("div.messages.success span").html()) != '') {
    $('.myDiv').addClass('.with-message');
  }
});
```

How can I have `myDiv` to have the `with-message` class when any message `span` is populated?

Note it ay be populated on the fly without reloading, or exist when landing on the page, or be populated with a reload.

Comment: What populates it?

Comment: Angular is populating the messages.

Comment: So why are you not using anular to add the class?

Comment: That's what I would have done originally, but It is outside of the scope. The messages controller has no relation to the myDiv element ...

Comment: So fire an event? listen for an event, set the ngClass ?

Comment: It is a little more complicated than just adding to the angular. That is why I am trying to do it outside of Angular.

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver

Comment: check this out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242

Comment: if you are the one asking for the content, then you know when the contents gonna come in, so you could just listen a custom event say _messageReceived_, then trigger it when the content has been loaded

Answer (score 1):

Two approaches:

**1.) Use MutationObserver ([supported IE11<](http://caniuse.com/#search=mutationobserver))**

```js
// select the target node
var target = $(".success")[0];
 
// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    // mutations.forEach(function(mutation) {
        console.log("div.success subtree changed");
    // });
});
 
// configuration of the observer:
var config = { childList: true}; // ,subtree: true, characterData: true 
 
// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);
 

setTimeout(function(){
  $(".messages").each(function(item,x){
    x.innerHTML = "content";
  });
},1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
<div class="message-container">
  <div class="messages error"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages success"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

**2.) Use the !deprecated! DOMSubtreeModified event. (Not recommended)**

You can try the following ([jsFiddle](http://jsbin.com/wapuve/edit?js,console,output)):

```js
 
$('.messages').bind("DOMSubtreeModified",function(){
  console.log('changed');
});

setTimeout(function(){
  $(".messages").html("content");
},1000);
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.0.js"></script>
  
<div class="message-container">
  <div class="messages error"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages success"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span></div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span></div>
</div>
</body>
</html>
```

One side effect I noticed, the event is fired twice.

**Warning:**

> The DOMSubtreeModified event type is defined in this  specification for
>   reference and completeness, but this specification deprecates the use
>   of this event type.

**Support:**

> DOMSubtreeModified is not supported in IE8 (and below)

Comment: Just a warning, this is deprecated... This question/answer has some good info: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2844565/is-there-a-javascript-jquery-dom-change-listener/11546242#11546242

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3

Comment: just added the warning :-)

Answer (score 1):

You can use a [MutationObserver](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/MutationObserver) to detect when a child was added.

```js
// select the target node
var target = document.querySelector(".messages.success");

// create an observer instance
var observer = new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
  document.querySelector(".myDiv").classList.toggle("active", mutations[0].addedNodes.length);
});

// configuration of the observer:
var config = {
  childList: true
};

// pass in the target node, as well as the observer options
observer.observe(target, config);

// later, you can stop observing
//observer.disconnect();

window.setTimeout(function() {
  var temp = document.createElement("div");
  temp.innerHTML = "Hello";
  document.querySelector(".messages.success").appendChild(temp);
}, 5000);
```

```css
.active {
  background-color: green;
}
```

```html
<div class="message-container">
  <div class="messages error"><span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="messages success"><span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span>
  </div>
  <div class="messages warning"><span></span>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="myDiv">...</div>
```

Or you can just poll the element and see if it has any children

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  updateDiv();
});

function updateDiv(){
  $('.myDiv').removeClass('.with-message');
  $.each($(".messages span"), function(){
    if($(this).text().length>0){
      $('.myDiv').addClass('.with-message');
    }
  });
  setTimeout("updateDiv()",3000);//periodically check for changes
}
```

Answer (score -1):

Assuming the user **types** into the field in question, all you need to do is run the check whenever a `keyup` or `keydown` or `keypress` event is triggered for the element in question:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("div.messages.success span").keyup(function(){
    if($.trim($("div.messages.success span").html()) != '') {
      $('.myDiv').addClass('with-message');
    }
  });
});
```

Note that `addClass()` should **not** pass the `.` along with the class name.

Assuming AngularJS is populating your fields (as your comments in the question say), you should apply the class directly with Angular, similar to:

```
app.controller('Ctrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.click = function() {
      angular.element('.myDiv').addClass('with-message');
    };
});
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: where did you get it was user typing? Nowhere in the question mentions typing.

Comment: Yeah, I slightly misread the question, and just assumed that `populate` would be typing into the relevant field. Looking at the class names though, it would likely be messages from some sort of external form submission.

Comment: Sorry, the user is not populating the messages.

Answer (score -1):

In addition to running initially, you can listen for new elements being created:

```
document.addEventListener("DOMNodeInserted", function(event) {
      if($.trim($("div.messages.success span").html()) != '') {
          $('.myDiv').addClass('.with-message');
      }  
})
```

Alternatively, take a look at Jquery's live call:
http://api.jquery.com/live/

EDIT:
The better approach would be to assign the class as you insert the new elements.

Comment: Correct, however the page explains that you can use .on for future elements

Comment: That is not going to detect DOM elements being added.