# How to address Jquery TE deprecated 'DOMSubtreeModified' DOM Mutation Event

Tags: jquery

I have started noticing the following warning in chrome:

> [Deprecation] Listener added for a synchronous 'DOMSubtreeModified' DOM Mutation Event. This event type is deprecated (https://w3c.github.io/uievents/#legacy-event-types) and work is underway to remove it from this browser. Usage of this event listener will cause performance issues today, and represents a risk of future incompatibility. Consider using MutationObserver instead.

I traced the source to a line in Jquery te 1.4

```
v.bind("keypress keyup keydown drop cut copy paste DOMCharacterDataModified DOMSubtreeModified", function() {
```

I downloaded the code again and currently available version is the same.  Is any update planned?

Is there an alternative wysiwyg text editor package to use that is not using this deprecated listener?

I have read the chrome docs and this listener will be removed by July 2024.

Comment: I would normally suggest getting the latest from the developer, but it appears [jquery TE](https://jqueryte.com/) hasn't been updated for 10 years.    So I suggest looking for a newer component.

Comment: "Is there an alternative wysiwyg" is specifically off-topic on SO: *Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more*

Comment: In the meantime, perhaps edit jqueryte.js and remove `DOMSubtreeModified`?  Perhaps you could replace it with the alternative that was available even 10 years ago:  See [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6659662/why-is-the-domsubtreemodified-event-deprecated-in-dom-level-3)

Comment: yep, replacing that bit with MutationObserver silenced the warning, thanks

Comment: if you want to post that comment as an answer i'll make it correct answer