# Understanding how Greasemonkey runs user scripts

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey

I'm learning Greasemonkey with the hopes of making some improvements to a webpage.

I think I have a good grasp of JavaScript, but I don't understand at what point in the rendering of the document the Greasemonkey user script is executed.

For instance, what if there is JavaScript natively inside the document that inserts some elements to the page. I want my Greasemonkey script to run only after that JS completes.

Let's say this is the document that I'm trying to modify with Greasemonkey

```
<html>
 <script>
   //insert a button with id="mybutton"
 </script>
</html>
```

I want the `<script>` code to complete before my Greasemonkey script is run, because I want to alter its background color.

Comment: Greasemonkey inserts code at a point [equivalent](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block#.40run-at) to `DOMContentLoaded`. Use `unsafeWindow.onload = function(){ ... }` if you want to execute code **after loading external content such as external js files**.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Greasemonkey [runs at the DOMContentLoaded event](http://wiki.greasespot.net/DOMContentLoaded) by default.  This means that everything will be in the page except for *possibly* large images and stuff added by some javascripts (scripts that fire on the `load` event or that AJAX-in content).

If you want to wait until even large media has loaded and "onload" scripts have run, use:

```
window.addEventListener ("load", Greasemonkey_main, false);

function Greasemonkey_main () {

    //***** PUT YOUR GREASEMONKEY CODE HERE.
}
```

**Do not use** `unsafeWindow.onload = function(){ ... }` or `window.onload = function() { /* logic here */ }` as others have suggested.  [These are not only poor practice/won't work in GM](http://commons.oreilly.com/wiki/index.php/Greasemonkey_Hacks/Getting_Started#Pitfall_.232:_Event_Handlers), but the `unsafeWindow` is an unnecessary security risk in this case.

---

---

### However, dealing with JS-added content:

Since you indicated that the node you care about is added by javascript, waiting for the `load` event will often not work.  JS can add, remove or edit nodes at any time.

The best approach in cases like these is to poll for the element you are interested in (`"#mybutton"`). See [this answer to "Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request"](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283815/331508).

Comment: As of Greasemonkey 3.6 you can also use `// @run-at      document-idle`, see http://stackoverflow.com/a/41667350/6216216.

Comment: @Leviathan, Use caution with that since it was borrowed from Chrome but does not operate the quite same way [Chrome does](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/content_scripts#run_at), nor how [Tampermonkey does](http://tampermonkey.net/documentation.php#_run_at).  If you use that directive, scripts may behave differently across browsers.