# How do I use JavaScript to store "XHR finished loading" messages in the console in Chrome?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, xmlhttprequest

I'm looking for a way to use JavaScript to store debug messages that appear in the Chrome console when xmlhttprequests are performed. Example output provided below:

[image]

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you simply want to do something every time any XHR load completes, like jQuery's [`.ajaxComplete`](http://api.jquery.com/ajaxcomplete/)? Or do you want to persist the log information for debugging reasons?

Comment: I believe the second option is what I need. I want to keep track of the URL's that the console is putting out, but as you can see, the XHR GET events in the first two lines belong to a different HTML and is inaccessible because of CORS. All I want to do is retrieve the URL string and store it in JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You cannot read console messages from JavaScript. You will not be able to read these messages.

However, using the same general concept as [John Culviner](https://stackoverflow.com/users/455556/john-culviner)'s answer to [Add a “hook” to all AJAX requests on a page](https://stackoverflow.com/a/27363569/710446), you can detect the events in JavaScript that cause these messages to appear.

```
(function() {
    var origOpen = XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open;
    XMLHttpRequest.prototype.open = function(method, url) {
        this.addEventListener('load', function() {
            console.log('XHR finished loading', method, url);
        });

        this.addEventListener('error', function() {
            console.log('XHR errored out', method, url);
        });
        origOpen.apply(this, arguments);
    };
})();
```

This overwrites every XHR object's `open` method with a new function that adds `load` and `error` listeners to the XHR request. When the request completes or errors out, the functions have access to the `method` and `url` variables that were used with the `open` method.

You can do something more useful with `method` and `url` than simply passing them into `console.log` if you wish.

Answer (score 0):

possible dublicate [How to read from Chrome's console in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19846078/how-to-read-from-chromes-console-in-javascript)

Comment: I suspect this is question isn't well-aligned as a duplicate of that question, since this question asks about a subset of console logging that is directly tied to a JS-visible event. That is, the answer here is probably "override `XMLHttpRequest.prototype.send` to bind a `load` listener to all XHR objects" whereas that's not an answer for the general problem of reading console output. It's more likely a duplicate of [Add a “hook” to all AJAX requests on a page](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5202296/710446) but I can't be sure without further clarification from the OP

Comment: i think there are not enough information about whats realy wanted by the question. definitly it's not possible to get access to the console of the browser. if he/she want's to capture the events he has to it with the basic event listeners

Comment: @TypedSource I'd like to retrieve the URLs being called by the html resource. It is from a different host, so there is a CORS restriction as well.

Comment: the console has a trace function. but from outside you can not access this is think.