# How can I check website content on every change?

Tags: javascript, tampermonkey

I have created a (tampermonkey) script to update a website title based on its content:

```
setInterval(function() {
    var activeSettingsPage = document.querySelector('[class$="dd_sublinks sel"]');
    if (activeSettingsPage != null){
        var activeSettingsPageName = activeSettingsPage.querySelector('.dd_sublinks_linkto').querySelector('.setuplink').querySelector('.setuplink_text').textContent;
        document.title = activeSettingsPageName;
    }

    const DEFAULT_TITLE_ENDING = ' - Zoho CRM';
    if(document.title.includes(' - Zoho CRM')){
        document.title = document.title.replace(DEFAULT_TITLE_ENDING,'');
    }
});
```

I have used a `setInterval()` function to run it in an endless loop. Is it a correct solution? Or is there anything better? (From performance, code readability, etc... aspects)

*Note: If I will remove `setInterval()` my tampermonkey script will check the website content only once at the beginning. That is not what I am looking for.*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might also wish to review the various answers in [this thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12897446/userscript-to-wait-for-page-to-load-before-executing-code-techniques), which additionally covers:

- `// @run-at      document-idle`
- using promises
- Brock Adams' `waitForKeyElements()` utility

Note that the `waitForKeyElements()` utility, as originally written, requires jQuery.

[Here is an updated/revised fork](https://github.com/CoeJoder/waitForKeyElements.js) of the `waitForKeyElements()` utility that:

- does not require jQuery
- avoids the quirks associated with `setInterval()`
- optionally takes a function (instead of a string) for querying elements on page

Answer (score 1):

You can use a MutationObserver which lets you know when a node (and a title is a node) has changed.

```js
new MutationObserver(function(mutations) {
    console.log("title changed to: " + document.title);
}).observe(
    document.querySelector('title'),
    { subtree: true, characterData: true, childList: true }
);


setInterval(function() {
document.title = Math.random()
}, 1000)
```

```html
<title>hello world</title>
```

Comment: Thanks for the MutationObserver usage idea.