# Greasemonkey script works only after page reload

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, reload, page-refresh

I have written [this userscript](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5751-metal-archives-discography-pages-reviews-column-split-sortable-tables).

It's for the site metal-archives.com. 
 
When opening a band page ([example](http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Iron_Maiden/25)) you land to DISCOGRAPHY>COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY.
My script applies to that DISCOGRAPHY tab and it's sub-tabs
(COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY, MAIN, LIVES, DEMOS, MISC):  
It splits the column "Reviews" in two and makes the table sortable.

The problem that, whenever I open such a band page for the first time
the script is not executed, unless I do a page reload (F5) - then it always executed.

I've already tried:
enclosing the **whole script** with either of these:
`window.addEventListener('load', function() {`
or
`window.onload = function () { ... MY CODE... }, false);`
or, based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8772789/3231411)

```
window.addEventListener ("load", Greasemonkey_main, false);

function Greasemonkey_main () {

    //***** MY CODE
}
```

or, additionally, even enclosing **only line 104** of the script
(which initially calls two functions, to add the column and make it sortable) with
`window.addEventListener('load', function() {... MY CODE... }, false);`
but without success.

Comment: search for "wait for key elements"

Comment: Do you maybe have the website loading partial content?

Comment: Try rewriting your script using [waitForKeyElements](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508), or similar.  If you get stuck on that, open a new question. (Hint: also use `@require` for jQuery and tablesorter.)

Comment: Thanks for your useful comments, Kat Cox and Brock.
Brock, ok, I just opened this [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416049/greasemonkey-using-the-waitforkeyelements-utility-how-to-call-a-function-aft) because waitForKeyElements syntax seems too diffucult for me. Thanks for the hint, too.