# Greasemonkey (using the waitForKeyElements utility) - how to call a function after a specific element has been displayed on screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

(In continuance to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26407574/greasemonkey-script-works-only-after-page-reload)).
I've been writing [this userscript](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5751-metal-archives-discography-pages-reviews-column-split-sortable-tables) for the site metal-archives.com.
When opening a band page ([example](http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Iron_Maiden/25)) you land to DISCOGRAPHY>COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY.
My script applies to that DISCOGRAPHY tab
and it's sub-tabs (COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY, MAIN, LIVES, DEMOS, MISC) :
it splits the column "Reviews" in two and makes the table sortable.

I want initially (using the `waitForKeyElements` utility in my script in greasemonkey)
a function (which adds a column to the table, based on it's contents, `appendColumn(x)` )
to be called  **after** the table inside DISCOGRAPHY > COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY has been completely displayed  (I think this as: *after the last header of the table has been displayed)*.
The `id` value of the last header of that table (MISC.) is already stored in this array position: `myArray[end]`

So, my failed tries so far (based on [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508) that user Brock Adams kindly suggested in my initial question) are variants of:

```
function appendColumn(x){....}

function triggerCall(jNode) {   
       appendColumn(0);    or --> jNode.appendColumn(0);   
   }

waitForKeyElements (myArray[end], triggerCall);  // no parentheses after triggerCall
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming the `appendColumn` function works, as is, on reloads; then you would rewrite it slightly and call it from waitForKeyElements().

You don't need most of that rigamorole, just use class names `display` and `discog` for the selector.  Like so:

```
waitForKeyElements (".display.discog", appendColumn);

function appendColumn(jNode) {
    var tbl = jNode[0]; // table reference
    var i;
    var newCell, newText;    

    var tr = tbl.tHead.children[0],
    th = document.createElement('th');
    // THE REST OF THE FUNCTION IS THE SAME...
    //...
```