# Greasemonkey (waitForKeyElements + tablesorter) - in some cases the last column doesn't become sortable (having same values type and table structure)

Tags: javascript, jquery, greasemonkey

(In continuance to [this question of mine](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26416049/greasemonkey-using-the-waitforkeyelements-utility-how-to-call-a-function-aft)).

I've been writing [this userscript](https://greasyfork.org/scripts/5751-metal-archives-discography-pages-reviews-column-split-sortable-tables) for the site metal-archives.com.
When opening a band page (example) you land to DISCOGRAPHY | COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY
my script applies to that DISCOGRAPHY tab and it's sub-tabs (COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY, MAIN, LIVES, DEMOS, MISC)
it splits the column "Reviews" in two and makes the table sortable.

It's a simple script. It has two functions: `appendColumn()` and `sorting()` 
which are called:
the first after the discography table is completely displayed on screen,
and the latter after the new column "Ratings(avg)" is displayed (and uses the **[tablesorter](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/)**, a jQuery plugin)

The script works as expected for most of the pages ([example1](http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Iron_Maiden/25), [example2](http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Dio/163))
but **in some other pages, like this ([example3](http://www.metal-archives.com/bands/Andy_James/99613)) the last column doesn't not become sortable, not initially, nor in other the sub-tabs.**
*(that column column contains values that are percents (eg 50% ))*

---

*The only difference I've found between these 3 example pages, is that,

while in the 2nd and 3rd the sub-tab REPORT is missing (i.e the* `id` *of the first header of the table (COMPLETE DISCOGRAPHY) is* `#ui-id-6`  )  *-on the 1rd is* `#ui-id-7` -
*in the 2nd the column becomes sortable, while in the 3rd not.*
*And, the strange is that, I don't examine specific class names of headers or similar in my script.*

---

But, examining that last column header with Firefox Inspector devtool,
if you click on that (unsortable) column, then, looking at the DOM tree,
it toggles between `th.ratingsCol.header.headerSortUp` and `_SortDown`
-just like the other columns, which have become sortable, though- .

I call these two functions with these lines:

```
waitForKeyElements (".display.discog", appendColumn);
waitForKeyElements (".ratingsCol", sorting);
```

(the `.display.discog` is the class of the table,
and the `.ratingsCol` the class name of the new column's header)

For the latter, I've even tried, as an alternative:

```
waitForKeyElements ("#ui-tabs-1 > table:nth-child(1) > tbody:nth-child(2)> tr:nth-child(2) > td:nth-child(0)");
```

i.e  after displaying the first cell below the new column header too(not only the header),
but didn't make any difference.

Please help me.

Answer (score 0):

The problem was solved by using [the updated fork](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/) (([v2.17.8](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/christianbach/tablesorter/master/jquery.tablesorter.js)), most recently updated last month)
and not the [initial tablesorter release](http://tablesorter.com/docs/) ([v2.0.5b](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/Mottie/tablesorter/master/js/jquery.tablesorter.widgets.js), which is dated 2007)
Seems like that the initial version wasn't working alrightin some cases.