# How do I take text contained in web page and make it part of the page title?

Tags: tampermonkey, userscripts, greasemonkey-4

I desperately need help with writing a Tampermonkey/Greasemonkey script that takes part of the information within the web page and makes it part of the page (and window) title.

A client's name is part of the target (internal) web page, and clearly labeled within the HTML:

```
<div id="patient-info" class="ehr-patients-info">
    <div id="patient-identification">
        <span title="" id="patient-name">
            Johnnyfirst

            Smithylast
        </span>
    </div>
...
```

I want to add the text "Johnnyfirst Smithylast" to the window title and tried:

```
var ptname = document.getElementById("patient-name") ;
document.title = document.title + " | Name: " + ptname ;
```

But that resulted in titles like: ...`| Name: null`.

The second problem is that the web site to which I am piggybacking this userscript doesn't load all at once.  After the initial page load, there's heavy javascript functionality which loads various parts of the page and ends up displaying the client name as above.

When I try `$(window).on('load', function() { ... })`  or  `$(document).ready()`, it seems to be acting on a preliminary version of the web page that doesn't have the information fully loaded yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your target page is AJAX driven and [Greasemonkey/Tampermonkey fires way before most AJAX page loads finish](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8772137/understanding-how-greasemonkey-runs-user-scripts). So, you must use techniques like `MutationObserver`, `waitForKeyElements`, etc., to compensate.

For example, here's a complete *Tampermonkey* script that changes the title when it finds the `patient-name` node:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Put the patient Name in the title
// @match    *://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @noframes
// @require  https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// @grant    GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
// @grant    none
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.
/* global waitForKeyElements */
/* eslint-disable no-multi-spaces, curly */
'use strict';

waitForKeyElements ("#patient-name, .patient-name", scrapeTextToTitle);

function scrapeTextToTitle (jNode) {
    var nameRaw         = jNode.text ().trim ();
    var nameSanitized   = nameRaw.replace (/\s+/g, " ");
    document.title     += " | Name: " + nameSanitized;
}
```

Comment: Thank you for the quick response!  I noticed that you were the one who authored waitForKeyElements, but I never dreamed I'd get a response from Brock Adams himself!  Thanks for the help.  Will try it out once I get the chance. // Also thanks for editing my post; I was trying to strike a balance between being brief and explaining my motivation so that I wouldn't get replies like "Why would you even want to do it that way?  Just do it this way instead..."

Comment: Thank you, @Brock!  Your solution seems to work, for some circumstances.
Other circumstances I note that the patient name is denoted thus within the web page:
`<h3 class="patient-name ng-binding">Johnnyfirst Smithylast</h3>`
In your code, you have the "#" in front of the patient name.  Does that mean to look for "id=" in the tag?  Is there another character that means look for "class=" in the tag, such as "class=patient-name ng-binding"?

Comment: Sounds like I should find the descendant node for a class rather than an id, as in `<h3 class="patient-name ng-binding">`. I see that your waitForKeyElements() function already does that if I give an iframeSelector.

How do I specify an iframeSelector?  The website seems to use iframes, but there is no actual `<iframe>` tag in the code that I can see using Firefox's built-in Inspector.  How do I find info about the iframe in question and pass it to your Tampermonkey script? And is there a way to say "treat the entire document as your iframe" so it will search the whole thing?

Comment: @kwantum, See the updated answer and reference https://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/ .

Comment: It doesn't sound to me yet like you need to do anything special regarding iframes.  But there's plenty of Q&A's here on that if required.

Comment: The script seems to work in most of the AJAX-generated pages, except for the one I mentioned which inserts some 3rd-party content.  Somehow the script won't detect that content. This probably involves other aspects of Javascript, and I'll ask a separate question for this.  Thank you for helping me with the main issue of triggering Tampermonkey only after the AJAX content gets loaded!

I looked at your waitForKeyElements source code.  It calls itself recursively.  Wouldn't this eventually overflow if it waits a long time for elements that never appear?  Should I rewrite it as a loop instead?

Comment: @kwantum, waitForKeyElements  does not call itself recursively.  And you would have to invoke it scores of times on a massively bloated page to notice a performance hit.  Also, setting `bWaitOnce` to true (if applicable) causes it to unload after a single node is found.  But there are many ways to skin the same cat.  You don't need to use waitForKeyElements if you want to invent a new wheel.