# How can I run a Greasemonkey function after an AJAX update?

Tags: jquery, ajax, greasemonkey

I have a GM script that adds buttons next to certain hyperlinks on Facebook pages. However, any AJAX update nukes the buttons in that section of page (i.e. when you click 'view more comments' - all the buttons on that thread vanish)

What I **desire to do:**
Re-run my GM function after certain AJAX operations complete - mainly when viewing more comments & loading a new page (I.e click to a different group page, this is all AJAXed)

what I **currently do:**
Have a 30 second loop that just re-runs my code every 30 seconds. not ideal. Setting a shorter loop will just cause lag
*Edit - it actually makes more and more buttons.* Super *not ideal*!

**How you can help:**
what code should I use to trigger my function after AJAX finishes loading something?  What should I be doing so that my code only fires upon my desired AJAX updates, such as the 'new page' & 'more comments' updates?
*Edit - I need to re-run my code only on the updated bit (is this even possible?)*

Notes:
I have searched a bit and find a number answers for plain jQuery, asp.net, etc., but not the GM-jQ combo.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is a common problem.

Use the `waitForKeyElements()` function as shown in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/8283815/331508).

By default, it will handle every new element, of the type that you specify via jQuery selector, once each, and within milliseconds of that new element appearing.

~~~
Link to the target page and specify exactly what you are doing for a more specific application.

Comment: thank you good sir @brock - i will give this a whirl and see how i go.  
as for specifics i already explained at the top of my question. any facebook page & i am inserting a button next to certain hyperlinks (rallycries for DotD to be exact).