# How to click a Button with specific text?

Tags: javascript, button, greasemonkey

I am trying to modify the script below to click a button that looks like this on a site:

```
<button id="checkPrice-02070" onclick="checkPrice(02070,null); return false;" class="orangeDark">
  <span>check price</span>
</button>
```

I am using the code below. So far, the page seems to keep reloading; nothing else happens.
Any advice to someone new?

```
(function () {
    window.addEventListener("load", function (e) {
        clickConfirmButton()
    }, false);
})();

function clickConfirmButton() {
    var buttons = document.getElementsByTagName('button');
    var clicked = false;
    for (var index = 0; (index < buttons.length);  index++) {
        if (buttons[index].value == "check price") {
            buttons[index].click();
            clicked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!clicked) {
        setTimeout("window.location.reload()", 300 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1, accepted):

A `<button>`s `value` is not the visible text.  You'd want to search `textContent`.

**However:**

1. If that sample HTML is correct, you'd be better off searching for ids that start with `checkPrice`.  See the code below.
2. Are you sure you want to *reload* if the button is not found?  If it is added by AJAX this is not the best approach.  See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10476659/331508).
3. Don't use `setTimeout` with a string (to evaluate) argument like that.  See the code below.
4. You do not need to wrap the code in an anonymous function.

Anyway, this should work, given the sample HTML:

```js
window.addEventListener ("load", clickConfirmButton, false);

function clickConfirmButton (zEvent) {
    var button = document.querySelector ("button[id^='checkPrice']");
    if (button) {
        button.click ();
    }
    else {
        setTimeout (function () { location.reload(); }, 300 * 1000);
    }
}
```

---

---

To check the button text anyway, use:

```js
function clickConfirmButton (zEvent) {
    var buttons = document.querySelectorAll ("button[id^='checkPrice']");
    var clicked = false;

    for (var index = 0, numBtn = buttons.length;  index < numBtn;  ++index) {
        if (/check price/i.test (buttons[index].textContent) ) {
            buttons[index].click();
            clicked = true;
            break;
        }
    }
    if (!clicked) {
        setTimeout (function () { location.reload(); }, 300 * 1000);
    }
}
```

Comment: Excellent! It works but the page continously clicks the button without waiting any amount of time (even if I adjust the setTimeout to 300000 x 1000). Any advice on how to add additional wait?

Comment: You're saying that it clicks the button but then reloads the page anyway?  Or somehow auto-clicks more than once?  If either of those is true, then the question doesn't match the actual page, or the GM script has something else going on besides the indicated code. ... Link to the target page and post the complete script you are using.  (Edit the question, or open anew question or use http://pastebin.com/.)

Comment: @BrockAdams I don't understand the syntax with the ```/``` symbols in this context ```/check price/i.test```. Could you please point me to the correct  resource to learn more.