# Overriding Storage method from content script

Tags: javascript, local-storage, overriding, content-script, session-storage

Is there any way to override `localStorage` and `sessionStorage` object's methods from content script? I am trying to disallow inline script to clear storages by executing this code from my Chrome extension (content script that runs before page is loaded). The code is:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         StorageSaver
// @match        http://barbars.org/*
// @grant        none
// @run_at       startup
// ==/UserScript==
/* jshint -W097 */
'use strict';

// Your code here...
location.href = "javascript: localStorage.clear = function(){alert('local works!');}";
location.href = "javascript: sessionStorage.clear = function(){alert('session works!');}";
```

Comment: you can clear localStorage without calling any methods using delete+for-in...

Comment: your code works in the console on this page, so the clear() method CAN be overwritten, sounds like it's just not getting done.

Comment: I am sure that the storages are being cleared every time page refreshes from inline script that is located in `<head>` section. And this script is using `.clear()` method to clear both storages.

Comment: do you need localStorage to function? you might be able to freeze() it

Comment: What I need is to prevent my key-value pairs from clearing after page is refreshed. My script is using them to know what to do on next page refresh and inline script is erasing them.

Comment: you could use another storage mechanism. cookies, window.name, indexedDB, sharedWorker, etc

Comment: Can you advice me such simple storage as local or session? Cookies are more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

Ah, I believe you are trying to execute

```
window.localStorage.clear = function() {};
```

*in* your content script. Your content script has a different `window` than the page's, so that won't work. A workaround would be as simple as this:

```
location.href = "javascript: localStorage.clear = function(){}";
```

or injecting a `<script>` tag.

This will be executed in the page instead of the scope of your content script.

Comment: But will it work if inline script is executing these methods using `window`? Like that:

    window.localStorage.clear();
    window.sessionStorage.clear();

Comment: The `window.` is redundant, since you are executing the code in `window` already (the global scope).

Comment: Just tried to replace two lines in content script as you said. No result. The storages continue to be cleared after each refresh.

Comment: When are you executing the content script? Are you running it at `document_start`?

Comment: Some more info. I have added alert to overwritten method. It works, but storage is still empty after refresh. Maybe it executes both methods (base and overwritten)? I am running it at `document_start` btw.

Comment: Maybe the page isn't really executing `.clear` but actually removing each entry one by one instead?

Comment: I am sure it is. Some more info. I get alert from overwritten method only when I manually refresh page (press button in browser) but when I am navigating from page to page using links I recieve no alerts. I am sure that every page has the same script in `<head>` section.

Comment: Since I don't have the page that you are talking about, I don't think I can solve the problem you are facing effectively.

Comment: @JohnSmith I made a quick test with Tampermonkey which executes the code on that site with `document_start` and it did work. The local storage entries are preserved.

Comment: I have updated question and added TM script. What's wrong with it?

Comment: You have to set the `run_at` in the settings panel. http://i.stack.imgur.com/N03PV.png

Comment: Yes, sorry. It's `run_at stratup` in my script. But it continues to alert me only on manually refresh, but no results after link clicks.

Comment: I figured out that my problem is very similar to this one:
[link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10456392/greasemonkey-script-only-runs-when-page-is-reloaded)
I have noticed `wicket:interface` in urls so I think the problem is with AJAX. But I am not familiar with it so I am expecting some suggestions.