# Script to fire an event as soon as an element exists?

Tags: jquery, ajax, facebook, greasemonkey

I'm trying to write a little Greasemonkey script for achieving some tasks in Facebook, like hiding news and such.

The problem is: I'm having an ID to an element which isn't existing yet in the DOM. It's the little box which appears when hitting a post's arrow-icon.

How can I create an event handler through jQuery which fires as soon as the element exists?

Comment: [jQuery.on](http://api.jquery.com/on/) lets you trigger for all elements that match a selector beneath a parent node, so you can configure events in advance but I'm not sure there's an 'on element created' or 'on child created' event. There's [jcade](https://github.com/snesin/jcade) but it sounds like this uses a planned-to-be-deprecated mechanism.

Answer (score 1):

This is a common problem.  You can act on AJAXed-in elements as they appear by using [the `waitForKeyElements()` utility](https://gist.github.com/2625891). (See ["Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request"](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8281441/331508) for example.)

I'm not sure what you mean by "the little box which appears when hitting a post's arrow-icon", but in general, you would:

1. Make sure your script has jQuery.  Add this to the [metadata section](http://wiki.greasespot.net/Metadata_Block), if it's not there already:

   ```
   // @require http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
   ```
2. Require-in `waitForKeyElements`:

   ```
   // @require https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
   ```
3. Write your handler function and activate it:

   ```
   function hideTheNews (jNode) {
       //***** YOUR CODE HERE *****
       jNode.hide (); // For example
   }

   waitForKeyElements ("*APPROPRIATE jQuery SELECTOR*", hideTheNews);
   ```

Comment: Alternatively, here's a jQuery plugin that I just forked from your script: https://gist.github.com/4200601

````$(selector).waitUntilExists(hideTheNews);````