# How to run a selector on a dynamically generated page?

Tags: jquery, ajax, google-chrome, tampermonkey

I have a selector which works in `GM_addStyle` but not in jQuery. I want to use jQuery `:contains()` which is not available in CSS3.

But, it appears that the id does not exist on my page when I view source but it's dynamically generated.
How do I tell Tampermonkey to run JS after the whole page loads?

I have tried different JS `@run-at` settings but no luck.

```
//works
GM_addStyle(" \
   #T301444200 > tbody > tr.SelPrimary > td:nth-child(1) > nobr > span{ color: red; } \
");

//does not work
$("#T301444200 > tbody > tr.SelPrimary > td:nth-child(1) > nobr > span").css("color","blue","important");
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281441/fire-greasemonkey-script-on-ajax-request)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sometimes you can wait for the window `load` event, but in general, you must use AJAX-aware techniques. See [Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281441/fire-greasemonkey-script-on-ajax-request).

So, using [waitForKeyElements()](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11197969/331508), a complete Tampermonkey script would be like:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name     _Use jQuery on AJAXed content
// @match    http://YOUR_SERVER.COM/YOUR_PATH/*
// @require  http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require  https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant    GM_addStyle
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directive is needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements (
    "#T301444200 > tbody > tr.SelPrimary > td:nth-child(1) > nobr > span", styleNode
);

function styleNode (jNode) {
    jNode.css ("color", "blue");
}
```

---

Note that `.css("color","blue","important");` is [not valid jQuery](http://api.jquery.com/css/) and is probably not needed in this case.

If this is one of the rare sites where you *do* need `!important`, use:

```
jNode[0].style.setProperty ("color", "blue", "important");
```

Inside `styleNode()`, above.

Answer (score 0):

[Waiting for the element](http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2016/01/20/waiting-for-stuff-with-javascript/):

```
function waitForElement(id, callback, timeout){
    if('undefined' == typeof timeout) timeout = 30;
    timeout = timeout * 1000;
    var time = 0;
    var poops = setInterval(function(){
        if(time >= timeout) clearInterval(poops);
        if(document.getElementById(id)){
            clearInterval(poops);
            callback();
        }
        time += 100;
    }, 100);
}
```

[One way to include jQuery](http://blog.geneticcoder.com/2015/10/04/include-jquery-in-a-userscript-via-closure/):

```
(function(callback) {
  var script = document.createElement("script");
  script.setAttribute("src", "//code.jquery.com/jquery-1.11.3.min.js");
  script.addEventListener('load', callback);
  document.body.appendChild(script);
})

// main codez go in here
(function(){
  window.alert($('a').length+" Links");
});
```