# Userscript getElementsByTagName not returning all links of Jira page

Tags: javascript, jira, userscripts

I need to make my Jira page on internal network show my assignee name in red color using a userscript without any external code use - no jQuery etc. And be as simple as possible, as I'm just learning.
Example page is here (List view): https://jira.atlassian.com/issues/?filter=-5

My internal page has following tag with my name in it, like this:

```
<a class="user-hover" rel="myusername" id="assignee_myusername" href="https://jira.mydomain.org/secure/ViewProfile.jspa?name=myusername" target="_parent">Myfirstname Mylastname</a>
```

My userscript is only making color changes on top and bottom lines of the page (I am logged in; it changes most links for userspecific ones). But the middle, where list of cases and assignees is listed, doesn't get affected. Here is my script:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name           Jira
// @namespace      https://jira.mydomain.org/secure/Dashboard.jspa
// @include        https://jira.mydomain.org/*
// ==/UserScript==
var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
var element;
    for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
    element = links[ i ];
    if ( element.id = "assignee_myusername" ) {
        element.style.color = "red";
        element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
    }
}
```

How do I make it highlight my name in Assignee column?

P.S. This is not same as the Ajax question, as that uses external code, which I specified in the beginning - no external code. No external code.

Comment: It could be that some of the content is loaded via XHR and your script needs to be called multiple times. How are you executing your script?

Comment: I am not specifically executing it, Ninjakit does - the whole script is in my post. I think it gets executed after page is loaded.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281441/fire-greasemonkey-script-on-ajax-request)

Comment: I don't think assignee_myusername is an existing ID on those pages

Comment: No jQuery, no external scripts, how is that duplicate of that AJAX question?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that the parts of the Jira page you want to script have not been loaded when your user script executes. Jira uses Ajax to load parts of the page asynchronously. Try adding a `setTimeout` around your code:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var links = document.getElementsByTagName( 'a' );
    var element;
    for ( var i = 0; i < links.length; i++ ) {
        element = links[ i ];
        if ( element.id = "assignee_myusername" ) {
            element.style.color = "red";
            element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
        }
    }
}, 1000);
```

This will highlight the link after one second. It's a hacky solution, but if it works, then that at least will show you that the async loading is, in fact, the problem.

If you just want to change the style of an element with ID “assignee_myusername”, you don't need to use `getElementsByTagName`, you can use `getElementById`:

```
window.setTimeout(function () {
    var element = document.getElementById( 'assignee_myusername' );
    element.style.color = "red";
    element.style.backgroundColor = "black";
}, 1000);
```

Comment: Just adding the timeout function makes every link on the page colored. But as soon as I change if to have additional criteria:
    && element.rel="myusername"
nothing gets highlighted.
And getElementById only does one element, getElementsById again does absolutely nothing.

Comment: Pardon my beginner mistake! Comparison is ==, not =. Tried it on the public page (not logged in) on one of reporters with multiple reported cases and got all links with his name, which was weird. And then it came like a fist in my face - "==", now it works like a charm.

Comment: Right, I overlooked that. For what it's worth, you should always use ===, not ==. Double equals sign is deprecated, for all practical purposes.

Comment: I also did some Jira tweaking with user scripts, already a few years ago, don't know if they still work with current jira version. But they may be interesting for you as reference: https://github.com/pahund/grease-that-monkey