# Usercript access to Dynamically generated (Vaadin framework) content

Tags: javascript, greasemonkey, userscripts, tampermonkey

I'd like to get access in javascript to DOM elements generated by Vaadin bootstrap. Let's say page: `https://vaadin.com`.

If you check the website content in *Chrome > inspect element* everything seems fine. We can navigate between html elements and everything is fine. But the content won't be displayed in *Chrome > view page source*.

Anyway, if we run a script like this in Tampermonkey:

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name         TEST
// @namespace    http://tampermonkey.net/ 
// @version      0.1
// @description  try to take over the world!
// @author       You
// @match        https://vaadin.com/
// @requirehttp://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js
// @require      https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// ==/UserScript==

console.log($('.front-page-view'));

$(document).ready(function () {
    console.log($('.front-page-view').html());
});
```

or even in "console" command (if page with above script is loaded) like:

```
$('.front-page-view').html();
```

every time we got

```
undefined
```

How do we get the userscript to see this code?

Comment: There doesn't seem to be a `.front-page-view` node on [https://vaadin.com/](https://vaadin.com/) (home page), even after the page is fully loaded.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Closely related to: [Fire Greasemonkey script on AJAX request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8281441/fire-greasemonkey-script-on-ajax-request).

The userscript fires long before the `.front-page-view` node(s) is/are loaded. So, the existing code sees nothing.

Here's how to `waitForKeyElements` to compensate for that (**complete working script**):

```
// ==UserScript==
// @name        Vaadin.com, show code of dynamic element
// @match       https://vaadin.com/*
// @require     https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.0/jquery.min.js
// @require     https://gist.github.com/raw/2625891/waitForKeyElements.js
// @grant       GM_addStyle
// @grant       GM.getValue
// ==/UserScript==
//- The @grant directives are needed to restore the proper sandbox.

waitForKeyElements (".front-page-view", showNodeHTML);

function showNodeHTML (jNode) {
    console.log ("FPV html: ", jNode.html().trim() );
}
```

Pay close attention to the metadata block as the question code has errors there.

Comment: Thank you for the quick answer. To be honest, I also experimented with "waitForKeyElements" function, without any success. At now, I execute this code in chrome (v 66) & tampermonkey and  ... showNodeHTML function is not called. Anyway, seems that in firefox & greasemonkey it works! 
Not sure what is the reason, I should check it also in ff on the beginning. 
Thanks once again.

Comment: The script works perfectly in Chrome.  But I just verified that **[that page](https://vaadin.com/) serves different content to Firefox than it does to Chrome!**  There is no node with the class `front-page-view`served to Chromium-based browsers.  But there is one served to Firefox.